# How to remove bottom white space when adding nib file to scrollview

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am adding a nib file to my scrollview

```
let camView : CamScrollViewController = CamScrollViewController(
            nibName: appConstant.nib_CamScrollViewController,
            bundle: nil)

self.addChildViewController(camView)
self.mainScrollViewHolder.addSubview(camView.view)
camView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

when i run this code I see there is white space in the bottom of the screen

[image]

How to remove this ?

Comment: By setting frame of CamScrollViewController you can remove white space from bottom.

Comment: Try to set the frame of camScrollViewController same as its super view. It will solve the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All you need to do is to set the frame of the `CamScrollViewController` to the same as the parents view's frame.

```
let camView : CamScrollViewController = CamScrollViewController(
            nibName: appConstant.nib_CamScrollViewController,
            bundle: nil)
// Set the frame of camView to the parentView's frame size
camView.view.frame = self.view.frame

self.addChildViewController(camView)
self.mainScrollViewHolder.addSubview(camView.view)
camView.didMove(toParentViewController: self)
```

Comment: are you doing this in `viewDidLoad`?

Comment: try it in `viewWillAppear`

Comment: also, have you set up `mainScrollViewHolder` constraints properly?